# How to get a pre-defined attribute of another Class

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to selectively `load_extension` by using a pre-defined attribute. Though I cannot figure how to properly get the object name.

With the below I am getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'default_state'`

```py
class Bot(Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        self._cogs = [p.stem for p in Path(".").glob("./testbot/bot/cogs/*.py")]

    def setup(self):
        cogs_to_load = [cog for cog in self._cogs if hasattr(cog, cog.default_state == "loaded")]

        for cog in cogs_to_load:
            self.load_extension(f"testbot.bot.cogs.{cog}")
```

An example of a cog below

```py
class Test(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: Bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot
        self.default_state = "loaded"
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally sure what you are trying to do, but I can try and help describe the error. Added some comments to your code.

```
class Bot(Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        # self._cogs is a list of strings here.  You get all the .py files and grab the basename/stem, which is a string.
        self._cogs = [p.stem for p in Path(".").glob("./testbot/bot/cogs/*.py")]

    def setup(self):
        # Looping over the self._cogs, you expect them to be Cog's with the default_state attribute, but they are still strings.
        cogs_to_load = [cog for cog in self._cogs if hasattr(cog, cog.default_state == "loaded")]

        for cog in cogs_to_load:
            self.load_extension(f"testbot.bot.cogs.{cog}")
```

If you want the class defined in the .py files you are looking for, then you'll need to import the module.  Then you can import the classes, or do a `dir` to get a list of the classes.  But until you import the class and instantiate it, you can't reference `default_state` on anything.

Comment: If I may ask a question... Is there any way to get the attribute, without importing the module, with `dir` alone?

Since the cogs are basically Classes, I have to loop through the list->check for some indicator(an attribute in my case)

I did the the following `for cog in cos_to_load: print(cog.__dir__())` . I got a ton of attributes but I saw no `default_state`

Comment: That's because you are stil dir'ing a str.  `dir` (or `__dir__`) only works on python objects, and the python class you seek must be imported for it to become inspected like that.  Your options, if you really don't want to import it.  1) Regex the contents of the file.  2) Use the `ast` module to parse the file and pull out the class name and then the attribute you want.

Answer (score 0):

The cog object is a string. The property default_state does not exist on a string. (For any object, you can see various properties by calling ._*dir*_() on it.)

Also, your hasattr method should look something like hasattr(instance_object, 'property_name'). The second argument you supplied here would evaluate to a boolean value, not an attribute name, given that it made sense to call cog.default_state. So that would also throw an error.